# Javascript : add hidden class on element

Tags: javascript, class, element

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><div class="menu-name sub-list-item" sb_action="my_ads">Mes annonces</div></a></li>
   <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><div class="menu-name sub-list-item" sb_action="my_feature_ads">Annonces Premium</div></a></li>
```

I want to add the class .ishidden to the second "li" element.

This is what I have done (not working for some reasons):

```
   const sb_actionID = "my_features_ads";
 const EL_features=document.querySelector(`[sb_action="${sb_actionID}"]`);
 if (EL_features) {
 EL_features.closest("ul > li").classList.add('is-hidden');

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in:

```
const sb_actionID = "my_features_ads";
```

It should be

```
const sb_actionID = "my_feature_ads";
```

and the parent is a.

You want the parents parent

Comment: @PaulMartinez, Typo is one part but if you want to apply the class to ```li``` even it won't work.. To target li follow this example https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/vYOxeMb

Answer (score 0):

The parent node of your `div` is `a` not `li`.

Comment: yes I notice that but even the a element is not targeted by the query.

Comment: I edited the code to target the closest elementbut still not working ...

Comment: Your element has an attribute `my_feature_ads` while the query uses `my_features_ads`. Note the "s" at the end of "feature".